# How to group by two fields whose value my be same and count them

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, group

i have a collection named players, below is the sample document. now i want to fetch the user-wise count of players for which the user is either mentor or owner or both. help me with a mongodb aggregation pipeline. (here user means owner or mentor)

```
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("32521df3f4948bd2f54223"),
        "firstName": "Olivia",
        "lastName": "Moore",
        "email": "olivia.moore@abc.com",
        "owner_id": ObjectId("32521df3f4948bd2f54988"),
        "mentor_id": ObjectId("32521df3f4948bd2f12343")
    },
```

`

i tried below aggregation. but user wise count not accurate.

```
db.players.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: { $ifNull: ["$owner_id", "$mentor_id"] },
            playerCount: { $sum: 1 }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            user_id: "$_id",
            playerCount: 1,
            _id: 0
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: What you're looking for isn't very clear to me. If you have `owner_id` of `A` and `mentor_id` of `B` for one document, should that single doc count once toward _both_ sums?

Comment: yes. that document should be part of both users's (A and B) bucket.

Comment: ... and if you have `"owner_id": "A"` and `"mentor_id": "A"` in one document, should that single doc count once or twice for `"user_id": "A"`?

Comment: it should be counted as one. under user_id: "A"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, here's one way you may be able to *"fetch the user-wise count of players for which the user is either mentor or owner or both."*

```js
db.players.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "ownersMentors": {
        "$setUnion": [["$owner_id"], ["$mentor_id"]]
      }
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$ownersMentors"},
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$ownersMentors",
      "playerCount": {"$sum": 1}
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "user_id": "$_id",
      "playerCount": 1
    }
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/XDPoty6foNK).

Comment: in this case if a user is both owner and mentor for a player, under that user, count will be two for that player which is wrrong

Comment: @ChinnuB That's the purpose of `"$setUnion"`.  If a user _"is both owner and mentor for a player"_, it is only counted once.  If you look at the mongoplayground.net example, specifically after the first `"$project"` stage, you will not find any repeats.

Comment: got it and it works fine. thank you